# Service Fabric remote debugging required open ports

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I was wondering if anyone knew what ports had to be opened in the load balancer/nsg to enable remote cluster debugging for Service Fabric.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/configure-the-windows-firewall-for-remote-debugging

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-debugging-your-application#debug-a-remote-service-fabric-application